# What is the proper REST response code when the URI path is legitimate, but the parameters filter it out

Tags: rest

If I am looking for a collection of users, I will `GET /api/user`, which should return `200` and the users if I find them, `404` if there is no users collection. But what if I have a collection users, but there don't happen to be user in it now, or my request includes a filter that returns no results?

Let's assume I have 2 users, `[{name:"john"},{name:"jill"}]`

`GET /api/user` will return the above with a `200`.
`GET /api/user?name=john` will return `[{name:"john"}]` with a `200`

But what if no users match the search?

`GET /api/user?name=sam`

Do I:

1. Return `200` with an empty list
2. Return `204` since the list is empty (same thing, essentially)
3. Return `404`

I am OK with `GET /api/foo` should return `404`, since there is no such resource (no foo collection defined). I am also OK with `GET /api/user/10` should return `404` if there is no user with ID of 10, since there is no such resource.

But in the case of `GET /api/user` where there is such a resource, but no actual users in it, or in the case above with `GET /api/user?name=sam`, there *is* a users collection, and therefore `/api/user` is a valid path; it is just that there are none that match the given filter.

What would you return?

Thoughts?

Comment: IMO go with an empty array because it's (generally) easier for the client to handle empty arrays than different response codes. Not much in it. I think you're pretty much correct with everything else you've said...

Comment: @Scobal so you would do `200` with an empty array for `/api/user` with no users or `/api/user?name=sam`, and save `404` for an actual invalid path like `/api/foo` or `/api/user/10` where there is no user with id==10?

Comment: Yep. I also prefer `/api/users` :)

Comment: LOL! I also prefer `/api/users` over `/api/user`, but I find most others don't. So I do `users` in my projects but post here with `user`! Helps avoid the religious debates.

Comment: @Scobal write your suggestion as an answer...

Comment: I agree with @Scobal on the error codes - Empty list for valid empty resources and 404 for 'no such resource'. For your reference, here is [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179357.aspx) from MS on common REST error codes.

Comment: I tried it, I like it... but I cannot mark it as correct unless @Scobal writes it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, I prefer an empty array over a 204, but it's not clear cut.

This was the best discussion I could find about it:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/api-craft/wngl_ZKONyk/hI1n88FeUWsJ